# How to traverse a Seq with the Scrap Your Boileplate combinator "everything" in Shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scrap-your-boilerplate

I want to use the Scrap Your Boilerplate implementation in Shapeless to operate on some case classes but i'm stuck trying to figure out how to make the SYB combinator `everything` traverse a field of type `Seq[...]`.

For example, defining trees like:

```
abstract sealed class Tree[+A] extends Product with Serializable
case class  Leaf[+A](value : A)                       extends Tree[A]
case class  Node[+A](left : Tree[A], right : Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

to count the number of leaves, the following works very well

```
object countLeaves extends Poly1 {
  implicit def count[A]    = at((a : Leaf[A]) => 1)
  implicit def default[X] = at((x : X)       => 0)
}

object sum extends Poly2 {
  implicit final val add = at((i : Int, j : Int) => i + j)
}

scala> everything(countLeaves)(sum)(Node(Leaf(1), Leaf(2)))
res14: Int = 2
```

But when using a `Seq` to store the children instead fields in `Node`

```
case class  Node[+A](children : Seq[Tree[A]])         extends Tree[A]
```

then `everything` is not able to traverse the field children :

```
scala> everything(countLeaves)(sum)(Node(Seq(Leaf(1), Leaf(2))))
res1: Int = 0
```

I tried various things but nothing worked. I did not figure out either how to write a correct instance of `Data` for `Seq[...]`.

**UPDATE :** Adapting the `Data` instance for `List` from `shapeless.Data` seems to work out

```
implicit def seqData[P, T, R](implicit qt: Lazy[shapeless.poly.Case1.Aux[P, T, R]]): Data[P, Seq[T], R] =
  new Data[P, Seq[T], R] {
    def gmapQ(t: Seq[T]) = t.map(qt.value(_)).toList
  }
```